# Compare two file then replace the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

File1.csv

```
column1,column2,column3
hello,halo,20A
hello2,halo2,50A
hello3,halo3,50A
```

File2.csv

```
book1,book2
20A,10
50A,20
```

Output.csv

```
column1, column2, column3
hello,halo,10
hello2,halo2,20
hello23,halo3,20
```

I'm comparing the file between `File1 and File2`. If value of `File1 - column3` matched with the value of `File2 - book1` then copy the `File2 - book2` value and replace to `File1 - column3`. The expected result is the `Output.csv`

So far I refer to other resources and I did try this

```
import csv

with open('File1.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('File2.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file2 \
        ,open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    csv_reader2 = csv.DictReader(csv_file2)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    csv_writer.writerow([ 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'])

    for row1 in csv_reader:
        for row2 in csv_reader2:
            if row1['column3'] == row2['book1']:
                row1[ 'column3' ] = row2['book2']

        csv_writer.writerow(dict(row1).values())
```

The result replaces all the `File1` value without comparison. I'm not sure which part goes wrong.

I updated the csv file and expected output

Comment: Why aren't you using pandas?

Comment: I'm quite new in python. I just learn from basic read and write csv.

Comment: Your program is fine, you have problem in csv files. You are giving spaces after comma, that is not needed. So either you remove useless spaces from the csv files Or trim the spaces in your program

Comment: @KamalNayan oh....I giving the space is because allow you guys to read it easily. I change it now

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to python I would also suggest learning how to use pandas which makes dealing with csv files very easy and intuitive. This answer is just a suggestion for an alternative method. You can achieve your desired results in pandas as well as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read the files
df1=pd.read_csv('File1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('File2.csv')

# Merge the two dataframes(tables)
result=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on=['column3'],right_on=['book1'])

# Delete the unwanted columns (because merge returns both column3 and book1)
result.drop(columns=['column3','book1'],inplace=True)

# Rename the column book2 to column3
result.rename(columns={'book2':'column3'},inplace=True) 

'''
Final result looks like this
column1, column2, column3
hello,halo,10
hello2,halo2,20
'''
```

You can use `print(result.head())` to see the final result. There is lot of support on SO for pandas and their documentation has many examples as well. Would be good to consider learning pandas if you are interested.

Here are the links to the documentation of the functions I have used in the code:

[read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

[drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

[rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Comment: @raxowogeh Its the exact same code for your edit as well. I would suggest use the link for merge and read about it. This [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) discusses various merges/joins in detail. Please refer to them.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the spacing issue which @Kamal Nayan mentioned, here's a simpler implementation which iterates over the two `csv_reader`s at the same time:

```
import csv

with open('File1.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('File2.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file2 \
        ,open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    csv_reader2 = csv.DictReader(csv_file2)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    csv_writer.writerow([ 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'])

    for row1,row2 in zip(csv_reader,csv_reader2):
      csv_writer.writerow([row1['column1'],row1['column2'],row2['book2']])
```

Output:

```
column1,column2,column3
hello,halo,10
hello2,halo2,20
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55721022-combining-CSVs

Comment: The link is `404`. But I did try your code. Same with my code, it didn't compare the value. Like example, if `column3` third row value is still `50A`. The result should be `20` too.

Comment: Fixed the link. What is the output supposed to look like if the values from `column3` and `book1` don't match?

Comment: it will keep checking others value until it matches.

Comment: And if there's no match at all?

Comment: it will set 0 for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt using csv module with a try-except approach:

example1.csv:

```
book1, book2
20A,    10
50A,    20
```

example2.csv:

```
column1, column2, column3
hello,   halo,     20A
hello2,  halo2,    50A
```

**Hence**:

```
import csv

reader1 = csv.reader(open('example2.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
next(reader1, None)    # skipping the headers

reader2 = csv.reader(open('example1.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
next(reader2, None)   # skipping the headers


while True:
   try:
      row1 = next(reader1)
      row2 = next(reader2)
      if (row1[2].strip() == row2[0].strip()):
          print("equal values: {}, {}".format(row1[2].strip(), row2[0].strip()))
      else:
          print("different values")
   except StopIteration:
       break
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
equal values: 20A, 20A
equal values: 50A, 50A
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas for that. The operation you want to do is called a join.

```
import pandas as pd

f1 = pd.read_csv("File1.csv", delimiter=';')
f2 = pd.read_csv("File2.csv", delimiter=';')

tmp = pd.merge(f1, f2, left_on='column3', right_on='book1')[['column1', 'column2', 'book2']]
tmp = tmp.rename(columns={'book2': 'column3'})

print(tmp)
```

The last stept is only to rename the last column.

```
   column1 column2  column3
0   hallo    halo       10
1   hallo    halo       20
```